# Example of flasque but non-soft sheaves?

Tags: sheaf-theory

Does anyone have an interesting examples of a flasque but not soft $\mathscr{O}_X$-module over a ringed space? Of course with $X$ being non-paracompact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question in the right way, no-one can have.

Citing [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_sheaf#Flasque_or_flabby_sheaves):

> Flasque sheaves are soft and acyclic.

So you cannot have a flasque but non soft sheaf.

Comment: Thanks! I was stuck. But is actually not hard to prove.